# Cannot make Android ProgressBar show as horizontal determinate

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Whatever I do, I only get small circular indeterminate progress bar. What I need is horizontal determinate. I tried setIndeterminate(false) explicitly in the code, setting max and initial progress, pre-setting it visible, setting the style explicitly to @android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal or style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal - nothing helped, the scrollbar remained indeterminate circle. While in the Studio design preview it shows as horizontal progress all right (when made visible).
Any idea please on where I could be wrong?

The Android version is 5.0.

Layout excerpt:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Code snippets (space lines and irrelevant code removed):

```
    ProgressBar pbLoading;
    public void onCreate( Bundle _savedInstanceState ) {
    /* ... */
        pbLoading = findViewById( R.id.loadingProgress );
    /* ... */
    }
    public void onStartLoading() {
        pbLoading.setVisibility( ProgressBar.VISIBLE );
        pbLoading.setMax( 100 );
        pbLoading.setProgress( 0 );
    }
    public void onLoadProgress( double _progress ) {
        pbLoading.setProgress( (int)Math.round( _progress * 100 ) );
    }
    public void onDataLoaded() {
        fDataLoaded = true;
        pbLoading.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean-rebuild? or also invalidate cache and restart? your code should work

Comment: your code look correct, please check if you display correct layout file

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley - Did Invalidate Caches, then Clean Project, then Rebuild Project - didn't help. Also, it was done from another workstation, which forced complete re-deployment of the app due to different debug certificate. But thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: @PhanVanLinh - It's the only layout in the project that can be used by this activity. Also, the only one incorporating ProgressBar.

Comment: Can you please post the full xml code?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh - In the end you were right. I found that I override the layout in the app project (the one in question is from library project)

Comment: nice, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The problem description was not complete. This app uses the old-fashioned approach with placing most of its logic in library project and overriding individual aspects in application projects. So, it turned out that the layout was overridden by an almost-copy one with the same layout id in the application project.
The problem is solved now.